# Изменить public function

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменить функцию в класе через файл function.php, например public function name?

```
class Class_N1 extends Class_N2 {
public function name( $atts ) {
    //same code
}
public function name_2() {
    //same code
}
```

}

Я понимаю, что можно изменить целиком класс, через new Class_N1(). Меня больше интересует, есть ли возможность изменить только фрагмент public function name в function.php.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А зачем? Какая у вас задача?

Comment: Задачу опишите нормально

Comment: Эдуард, у меня задача изменить код плагина в function.php. И как я уже написал, нужно изменить только одну функцию из класса.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Фрагмент функции заменить нельзя. Только переопределить её целиком.

Comment: Ну и где тот умник, что минус поставил? Код пусть покажет, как в он в дочернем классе меняет только несколько строк из родительской функции. Очень хочется увидеть этот прорыв в объектно-ориентированном программировании.

Comment: Я не верно выразился. Не фрагмент в функции public function name а фрагмент в классе, т.е. я хочу изменить только одну функцию public function name в классе. Остальные функции останутся неизменными.

Comment: Ну и какие проблемы. Создаёте дочерний класс, и в нём переписываете функцию. Это базовые понятия наследования.

Comment: Смотрите на конкретном примере

Comment: class Class_1 { public function test1() { echo 'test1'; } public function test2() { echo 'test2'; } }

class Class_2 extends Class_1 { public function test1() { echo 'test2'; } }


Мне придется выводить через это:
$print_class = new Class_1();
$print_class->test1();

Т.е. в код плагина придется вносить изменения. И при любом обновлении все слетит. Я могу изменить функцию function test1() не затрагивая код плагина. Так надеюсь понятно? ) Спасибо!

Comment: Нет, непонятно. Плохо объясняете. Во-первых, этот код следовало бы добавить в вопрос. Читать многострочный код в комментариях - то ещё удовольствие. Во-вторых, и в-главных, нет описания того, где нужно использовать результат изменённой public function. Если вне плагина - можно переопределить и использовать. Если внутри плагина - ничего не поможет, тупик.

Comment: Ну вот вы ответили. Эта функция должна быть изменена и использована снова в плагине. Просто я хотел избежать проблем с обновлениями.

Comment: А проблема касаться плагина WPBakery Page Builder и функции buildQuery. Которую я просто хотел изменить в function.php

Comment: так или иначе спсибо, я понял, что это невозможно.